# Averaging only non-zero values and displaying the result in Minutes:Seconds in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, conditional-statements, average

I have a few columns coming into an SSRS report on Cisco UCCE data at the half hour level.

Management wants to see the values on the report in Minutes (The data coming in is in seconds) and they only want the averages to include values where the number of calls was above zero (Average time on a call does not make sense to include values of zero when there weren't any calls to take time on). They also do not want to see #Error in the cells that try to divide by zero or try to DateAdd against an empty string.

I have this horrendous expression which is supposed to do just that, but it does not work.

```
=iff(Floor(iif(count(iif(Fields!CallsHandled.Value=0, nothing
,1))=0,"",sum(Fields!AHT.Value)/sum(iif(Fields!CallsHandled.Value=0, nothing     
,Fields!CallsHandled.Value))) / 
60)="","",Floor(iif(count(iif(Fields!CallsHandled.Value=0, nothing 
,1))=0,"",sum(Fields!AHT.Value)/sum(iif(Fields!CallsHandled.Value=0, nothing 
,Fields!CallsHandled.Value))) / 60) &":"& Format(DateAdd("s", 
Avg(iif(count(iif(Fields!CallsHandled.Value=0, nothing 
,1))=0,"",sum(Fields!AHT.Value)/sum(iif(Fields!CallsHandled.Value=0, nothing 
,Fields!CallsHandled.Value)))), "00:00:00"), "ss"))
```

It attempts to determine which rows have a number greater than zero in the HandledCalls field and then average the AHT field by taking the sum of AHT and dividing it by the number of HandledCalls. Somewhere in this process it causes this error:

"The Value expression for the textrun ‘AHT.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30451] Name 'iff' is not declared."

to be thrown.

Has anyone here ever used SSRS to display an average calculated this way (using only non-zero entries) while simultaneously displaying that average, which contains only the number of seconds in a timespan, in minutes?

**EDIT:** There was a typo at the beginning of my expression. It no longer throws the error message when running the report, but now every cell contains #Error regardless of the HandledCall number.

Comment: As per the error `iff` is not a valid function, it's a typo right at the start of your expression; what happens when you replace it with `iif`?

Comment: You were right that there was a typo right at the beginning, but unfortunately the formula still doesn't work. Now every cell contains #Error regardless of the Call Number.

Answer (score 0):

In the first conditional test, the result of a count (which is either `""` or the average, based on the `iif` statement) is divided by 60.  Surprisingly, SSRS is ok with that and in the case of `""` / 60 you still get 0.  However the statement then goes on to test for equality of a number (either 0 or the average) and a string (`""`), which is going to result in the `#Error` you are seeing.

So basically compare numbers to numbers by changing `""` in the first condition to a 0:

```
=iff(Floor(iif(count(iif(Fields!CallsHandled.Value=0, nothing
,1))=0,"",sum(Fields!AHT.Value)/sum(iif(Fields!CallsHandled.Value=0, nothing     
,Fields!CallsHandled.Value))) / 60)=0,
"",
Floor(iif(count(iif(Fields!CallsHandled.Value=0, nothing 
,1))=0,"",sum(Fields!AHT.Value)/sum(iif(Fields!CallsHandled.Value=0, nothing 
,Fields!CallsHandled.Value))) / 60) &":"& Format(DateAdd("s", 
Avg(iif(count(iif(Fields!CallsHandled.Value=0, nothing 
,1))=0,"",sum(Fields!AHT.Value)/sum(iif(Fields!CallsHandled.Value=0, nothing 
,Fields!CallsHandled.Value)))), "00:00:00"), "ss"))
```

That should at least solve the `#Error`s you are seeing, but since that expression is gigantic I can't guarantee it'll solve everything!